# Unable to allocate memory with new[] from within templated function

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, memory-management

I am trying to create a function that allocates memory. It allocates it, but the problem is that it only appears to do so inside the function, but after it returns the memory allocated is no longer there. Almost as if I am allocating memory with another pointer, but there should be no other there.

```
template<class T> struct rmv_ptr { using type = T; };
template<class T> struct rmv_ptr<T*> { using type = T; };
template<class T> struct rmv_ptr<const T*> { using type = T; };

template<class T> bool alloc(T inst, int size)
{
    return (nullptr != (inst = new typename rmv_ptr<T>::type[size]));
}
```

Say I call it like this:

```
wchar_t* a;
alloc(a, 10);
```

`inst` will be `wchar_t*`, so `a`'s pointer should point to the allocate memory, no?

Comment: Hm does `T inst` need to be `T& inst`?

Comment: But I am passing a pointer, and the pointer should not change, no?

Comment: This is no different than something like this: `int foo(int x) { x = 10; }  int main() { int x = 0; foo(x); }` and `x` still is 0 after the call to `foo`.

Comment: You guys may just be right but I'd like some more explanation for this, as I am passing a pointer which is different from just passing an int, which would just copy the initial passed variable

Comment: @Hjkl -- No, the pointer doesn't change.  You're passing by value, and anything passed by value will not be reflected back to the caller.  Passing a pointer is *not* different than passing an int, double, or some other object *by value*.  The rules of C++ doesn't change because the value happens to be a pointer.

Comment: I see. I was confused because I can access and edit the elements in the wchar_t arrays without having to pass them by reference

Comment: If you looked at your code, you're changing the value of the pointer, not what it is pointing to, and then expected that changed pointer value to be seen by the caller.  No different than if you changed an `int` that is passed by-value within a function, and expected the caller to see the change.

Comment: Yeah, I get it, but my debugger does not show the address, just the value, so I could not clearly see it myself. You were right, it now works

Comment: You need something like a pointer to a pointer, so that the function can rewrite the pointer itself. A non-const reference is okay, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass an integer to a function, you cannot change the integer.

When you pass a pointer to a function, you cannot change the pointer.

When you pass a pointer to a function, you can change the pointed-to value.

Pass-by-non-const-reference is the exception; it allows you to change the passed value. Passing a pointer by reference therefore allows you to change the pointer.

---

On an unrelated note, the base rule for "remove pointer" template logic won't work. The problem is that you have two uses of `T`. There's the argument `T& inst`, which has to match `T*` returned by `new`. I.e. if `T` is `int`, then `rmv_ptr<int>::type` is `int`, and `new` will return an `int*`. But you can't assign that `int*` to `int& inst`.

Comment: Yes, I was in face confusing changing the pointer to changing the values of the pointer. My original code has another templated check to make sure that "inst" is in fact a pointer, but thanks for the note, I am a newbie to this these template hacks

Answer (score 1):

Pointers are no different from non-pointers as modifications are not visible outside when passed by value to a function:

```
void foo(int* p) { p = 0; }    // only modifies the local p
void foo(int  a) { a = 0; }    // only modifies the local a
```

However, pointers allow you to modify what the pointer does point to and that can be observed by the caller:

```
// assume p points to an int
void bar(int* p) { *p = 42; }
```

This will not modify `p` itself. When called via

```
int x;
int xp = &x;
bar(xp);
```

then `p` inside `bar` is a copy of `xp`, though they both point to the same `int`.

But when you call `new`, then `new` returns you a pointer to the allocated memory, so you need to change the pointers value, not just the pointee. Either pass it by reference, or return the pointer from the function (making it a parameter is of no use anyhow).